# Why does introducing time.sleep() in my Tkinter app cause the canvas not to render?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

In my Tkinter program, this program is intended to render 3 squares in the canvas, and change their color every second. I want this change to occur every second 100 times.
It works, as logging the current color will get printed in the terminal as expected, but when I introduce the sleep() method it causes the canvas to not load.

Any suggestions here?

```
from tkinter import messagebox
import time

top = Tk()
C = Canvas(top, bg="white", height=300, width=400)

coord1 = 30, 10, 120, 80
coord2 = 150, 10, 240, 80
coord3 = 270, 10, 370, 80

colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue']

for i in range(0,100):
    for x in range(0,3):
        C.create_rectangle(coord1, fill=colors[x])
        C.create_rectangle(coord2, fill=colors[x])
        C.create_rectangle(coord3, fill=colors[x])
        print(colors[x])
        # time.sleep(1)
        
C.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

Comment: Just as a style note: Capitalized names are typically reserved for classes in Python, while variables are given lowercase names. In this case, it'd be better (more "pythonic") to use something like `my_canvas = Canvas(...)` rather than `C = Canvas(...)`

Likewise, it's always best to [avoid star imports](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/why-import-star-in-python-is-a-bad-idea/) like `from tkinter import *` (which I assume was done here), as this can cause an issue known as "namespace pollution". For this reason, it's better/common practice to use `import tkinter as tk`

Comment: Remember that Tkinter, like all graphics libraries, is totally event driven.  None of your drawing commands actually do any drawing at all.  All they do is queue up drawing messages.  Nothing at all gets drawn until you call `mainloop`, which then starts draining and dispatching those messages.  It is the message handlers that do the drawing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using time.sleep(), the entire program is going to be paused, including the Tkinter event loop. This is why the canvas wouldn't be loading or updating as expected.

> Edit: Only the current thread is going to be paused, which includes the Tkinter event loop. Thanks to acw1668 for the clarification in a comment below.

To fix this you should use the `.after()` method of Tkinter. The method schedules a function to be called after a given amount of time (https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-after/). Using `.after()` allows you to create a delay without freezing the Tkinter GUI.

Here is what your updated code should look like:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas
import itertools

def change_color():
    color = next(color_cycle)
    C.itemconfig(rect1, fill=color)
    C.itemconfig(rect2, fill=color)
    C.itemconfig(rect3, fill=color)
    print(color)
    if change_color.counter < 100:
        top.after(1000, change_color)  # Schedule next color change after 1000ms
        change_color.counter += 1

top = Tk()
C = Canvas(top, bg="white", height=300, width=400)

coord1 = 30, 10, 120, 80
coord2 = 150, 10, 240, 80
coord3 = 270, 10, 370, 80

colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue']
color_cycle = itertools.cycle(colors)

# Create rectangles and store their references
rect1 = C.create_rectangle(coord1, fill="")
rect2 = C.create_rectangle(coord2, fill="")
rect3 = C.create_rectangle(coord3, fill="")

C.pack()
change_color.counter = 0  # Initialize counter for the number of changes
change_color()  # Start changing colors

top.mainloop()
```

The change_color function is defined to change color of the rectangles and then schedule itself to be called again every 1000milliseconds (1 second).

Let me know if you have any more questions about this.

Comment: Using `change_color.counter` might be confusing to new programmers who are yet to learn of OOP and how `change_color` is actually an object. It would be a bit easier for them to understand the code better if instead you used `counter` as a function argument. Especially those familiar with functional programming.

Comment: *"When using time.sleep(), the entire program is going to be paused"* is incorrect, only the current thread is affected.